Duplicate set of containers when running WSL with and without docker desktop
I have the following setup:

Windows (Host) - running docker desktop
WSL2 - /home/user/workspace/nxg contains my project files
Vscode connected with a Devcontainer

Project directory with relevant docker files:
.
├── .devcontainer
│   ├── devcontainer.json
│   ├── docker-compose.yaml
│   └── Dockerfile
├── docker-compose.build.yaml
├── docker-compose.yaml
├── Dockerfile
├── .dockerignore
├── .env
├── .env.docker
├── .env.sample
└── .vscode
    ├── launch.json
    └── tasks.json

devcontainer.json:
{
  "dockerComposeFile": ["../docker-compose.yaml", "docker-compose.yaml"],
  "service": "nxg",
  "workspaceFolder": "/workspace-nxg",
  "shutdownAction": "stopCompose",
    "customizations": {
    "vscode": {
      "settings": {
        "terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/bin/bash"
      },
      "extensions": [
        "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
        "ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-next",
        "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint"
      ]
    }
  },
    "features": {
    "ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/docker-in-docker:2": {}
  },
  "postCreateCommand": {
        "chown .pnpm-store" : "sudo chown node /workspace-nxg-/.pnpm-store", 
        "chown node_modules": "sudo chown node /workspace-nxg-/node_modules"
    }
}

When I start DD (Docker desktop) and then VSC (visual studio code) to load my project I see 3/3 containers running:

dev container
postgres container
nats container

This works great, I can query these container with docker ps -a and docker compose ls and both the containers are listed and the merged compose file by the devcontainer plugged is listed.
The problem and question:
The problem and question now is that I have another set of the exact same containers living somewhere in WSL. If I start VSC without DD it still works, these containers are not visible with docker ps -a and they're always running the moment I start WSL.
In this situation where DD is not running here is the output of various commands:
On Windows:
C:\Users\Rohan>docker compose ls
NAME                STATUS              CONFIG FILES

C:\Users\Rohan>docker container ls
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES

On WSL:
➜  ~ docker compose ls
NAME                STATUS              CONFIG FILES

➜  ~ docker container ls
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES

➜  ~ docker container ls -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                                                                       COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS                      PORTS     NAMES
86ca41fac541   nxg_postgres                                                                   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   24 hours ago   Exited (137) 17 hours ago             nxg-postgres-1
c5daa37c18a5   vsc-nxg-b04a8eb6a5643967ef9d6f249b515bf6a6b34dac403c5f6bdd4897ad7c3a9c67-uid   "/bin/sh -c 'echo Co…"   24 hours ago   Exited (137) 17 hours ago             nxg-1
e722162a3b66   nats:2.10.12                                                                                "/nats-server --name…"   4 days ago     Exited (1) 17 hours ago               nxg-nats-main-1

➜  ~ ls -l $(which docker)
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 35939040 Oct 26  2023 /usr/bin/docker
➜  ~ ls -l $(which kubectl)
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 55 Jul 25 16:18 /usr/local/bin/kubectl -> /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop/cli-tools/usr/local/bin/kubectl
➜  ~ ls -l $(which dockerd)
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 93546720 Oct 26  2023 /usr/bin/dockerd
➜  ~ ls -l $(which containerd)
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 52632728 Sep 15  2023 /usr/bin/containerd

Inside the devcontainer:
node ➜ /workspace-nxg (master) $ docker compose ls
NAME                STATUS              CONFIG FILES

node ➜ /workspace-nxg (master) $ docker container ls
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES

node ➜ /workspace-nxg (master) $ docker container ls -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES

WSL pgrep:
➜  ~ pgrep -ax "docker"
2016 docker exec -i -u root fc27d0ab8cb33c55a21abe7091464e5a100df6cd164ecb6af24665b448e9bb95 /bin/sh -c echo "New container started. Keep-alive process started." ; export VSCODE_REMOTE_CONTAINERS_SESSION=38abadb3-e52c-42a3-b8a4-29b11bc302a91721385658625 ; /bin/sh
2039 docker exec -i -u node -e VSCODE_REMOTE_CONTAINERS_SESSION=38abadb3-e52c-42a3-b8a4-29b11bc302a91721385658625 fc27d0ab8cb33c55a21abe7091464e5a100df6cd164ecb6af24665b448e9bb95 /bin/sh
2131 docker exec -i -u root fc27d0ab8cb33c55a21abe7091464e5a100df6cd164ecb6af24665b448e9bb95 /bin/sh
2216 docker exec -i -u node fc27d0ab8cb33c55a21abe7091464e5a100df6cd164ecb6af24665b448e9bb95 /bin/sh
2391 docker exec -i -u node -e SHELL=/bin/bash -e VSCODE_AGENT_FOLDER=/home/node/.vscode-server -w /home/node/.vscode-server/bin/f1e16e1e6214d7c44d078b1f0607b2388f29d729 fc27d0ab8cb33c55a21abe7091464e5a100df6cd164ecb6af24665b448e9bb95 /home/node/.vscode-server/bin/f1e16e1e6214d7c44d078b1f0607b2388f29d729/bin/code-server --log debug --force-disable-user-env --server-data-dir /home/node/.vscode-server --use-host-proxy --telemetry-level all --accept-server-license-terms --host 127.0.0.1 --port 0 --connection-token-file /home/node/.vscode-server/data/Machine/.connection-token-f1e16e1e6214d7c44d078b1f0607b2388f29d729 --extensions-download-dir /home/node/.vscode-server/extensionsCache --install-extension ms-azuretools.vscode-docker --install-extension esbenp.prettier-vscode --install-extension ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-next --install-extension dbaeumer.vscode-eslint --start-server --disable-websocket-compression --skip-requirements-check
2466 docker exec -i -u node -e VSCODE_REMOTE_CONTAINERS_SESSION=38abadb3-e52c-42a3-b8a4-29b11bc302a91721385658625 fc27d0ab8cb33c55a21abe7091464e5a100df6cd164ecb6af24665b448e9bb95 /home/node/.vscode-server/bin/f1e16e1e6214d7c44d078b1f0607b2388f29d729/node -e                               const net = require('net');                             const fs = require('fs');                               process.stdin.pause();                          const client = net.createConnection({ host: '127.0.0.1', port: 42707 }, () => {                                         console.error('Connection established');                                        client.pipe(process.stdout);                                    process.stdin.pipe(client);                             });                             client.on('close', function (hadError) {                                        console.error(hadError ? 'Remote close with error' : 'Remote close');          process.exit(hadError ? 1 : 0);                          });                             client.on('error', function (err) {                                     process.stderr.write(err && (err.stack || err.message) || String(err));        });                              process.stdin.on('close', function (hadError) {                                        console.error(hadError ? 'Remote stdin close with error' : 'Remote stdin close');                                       process.exit(hadError ? 1 : 0);                          });                             process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {                                        fs.writeSync(process.stderr.fd, `Uncaught Exception: ${String(err && (err.stack || err.message) || err)}\n`);                           });
2536 docker exec -i -u node -e VSCODE_REMOTE_CONTAINERS_SESSION=38abadb3-e52c-42a3-b8a4-29b11bc302a91721385658625 fc27d0ab8cb33c55a21abe7091464e5a100df6cd164ecb6af24665b448e9bb95 /home/node/.vscode-server/bin/f1e16e1e6214d7c44d078b1f0607b2388f29d729/node -e                               const net = require('net');                             const fs = require('fs');                               process.stdin.pause();                          const client = net.createConnection({ host: '127.0.0.1', port: 42707 }, () => {                                         console.error('Connection established');                                        client.pipe(process.stdout);                                    process.stdin.pipe(client);                             });                             client.on('close', function (hadError) {                                        console.error(hadError ? 'Remote close with error' : 'Remote close');          process.exit(hadError ? 1 : 0);                          });                             client.on('error', function (err) {                                     process.stderr.write(err && (err.stack || err.message) || String(err));        });                              process.stdin.on('close', function (hadError) {                                        console.error(hadError ? 'Remote stdin close with error' : 'Remote stdin close');                                       process.exit(hadError ? 1 : 0);                          });                             process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {                                        fs.writeSync(process.stderr.fd, `Uncaught Exception: ${String(err && (err.stack || err.message) || err)}\n`);                           });
21866 docker events --since 1721391815 --until 1721392115 --filter type=container --filter type=image --filter type=network --filter type=volume --filter event=create --filter event=destroy --filter event=die --filter event=kill --filter event=pause --filter event=rename --filter event=restart --filter event=start --filter event=stop --filter event=unpause --filter event=update --filter event=delete --filter event=import --filter event=load --filter event=pull --filter event=save --filter event=tag --filter event=untag --filter event=remove --filter event=prune --format {{json .}}

➜  ~ pgrep -ax "containerd"
56 containerd --config /var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.toml
1930 containerd --config /var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.toml

➜  ~ pgrep -ax "dockerd"
24 /usr/bin/dockerd -p /var/run/docker.pid
1888 dockerd

WSL lsof:
# With containers active

➜  Rohan sudo lsof -i | grep "LISTEN"
[sudo] password for user:
docker-pr 646 root    4u  IPv4  23613      0t0  TCP *:8222 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 653 root    4u  IPv6  26845      0t0  TCP *:8222 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 669 root    4u  IPv4  17628      0t0  TCP *:4222 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 675 root    4u  IPv6  17631      0t0  TCP *:4222 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 757 root    4u  IPv4  26901      0t0  TCP *:postgresql (LISTEN)
docker-pr 764 root    4u  IPv6  18649      0t0  TCP *:postgresql (LISTEN)

#With DD containers shutdown(same result)
➜  Rohan sudo lsof -i | grep "LISTEN"
docker-pr 646 root    4u  IPv4  23613      0t0  TCP *:8222 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 653 root    4u  IPv6  26845      0t0  TCP *:8222 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 669 root    4u  IPv4  17628      0t0  TCP *:4222 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 675 root    4u  IPv6  17631      0t0  TCP *:4222 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 757 root    4u  IPv4  26901      0t0  TCP *:postgresql (LISTEN)
docker-pr 764 root    4u  IPv6  18649      0t0  TCP *:postgresql (LISTEN)

Please keep in mind that I have previously installed docker/k3s on WSL before I switched to DD so when cleaning WSL of the old docker I might have left some files. I feel like the devcontainers plugin has some kind of "backup" manner of managing containers but I don't understand how to stop these containers and clean up their resources except for a killall and then also prevent this "backup" method.
I assume there's a service file somewhere that's starting these containers that I could delete but all of these are not the source of the problems in my opinion.
Hopefully I've provided enough info, there's logs I could add with and without DD of the devcontainer plugin but those contain sensitive information so I'd prefer to scrub them and upload them only if needed.
edit
At @Marcell Bolubás request I have added the output of whereis docker
#With DD
➜  ~ whereis docker
docker: /usr/bin/docker /etc/docker /usr/local/lib/docker /usr/libexec/docker /Docker/host/bin/docker /usr/share/man/man1/docker.1.gz

#Without DD
➜  ~ whereis docker
docker: /usr/bin/docker /etc/docker /usr/local/lib/docker /usr/libexec/docker /usr/share/man/man1/docker.1.gz

diff with findmnt shows /Docker/host gets added by Window's DD
├─/Docker/host                                            C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources
│                                                                                9p          rw,noatime,dirsync,aname=drvfs;path=C:\Program


If DD is not running and you removed the docker engine installation from the WSL2 distro then you should not be able to issue docker commands at all so most probably you still have docker engine installed inside the WSL2 distro that you should get rid of (if your goal is to use DD only)

I'm awarding the bounty because after reading your answer I checked my laptop with a similar setup and running docker ls without DD returns an error but I can't mark this as solved because I still have the problem of duplicate detached containers running. I'm wondering if somehow the 'restart': 'on-failure' policy of my compose file has caused containerd to create a systemd service for those detached containers.

Compose or container restart policy has nothing to do with this. You still have a docker engine installed inside your wsl2 distro (ubuntu or whatever you use) that you must remove properly. DD uses a separate wsl2 distro for itself, actually 2 instances, docker-desktop for the engine and docker-desktop-data for all the data that is stored in docker (images, containers, volumes etc). When you enable wsl2 integration in DD UI then you can reach DD docker engine from your wsl2 instance (ubuntu or whatever)

Is the docker command that's being run in WSL actually going to linux, and not to windows? Or alternatively are you using the DD WSL2 backend?
What is the output of whereis docker in WSL?

I have appended the ouput of whereis to the bottom of my question. Just to be clear, my main concern is figuring out why I have a duplicate set of containers, even if an old docker is still there it should report those containers right?
